# How can I get the menu bar in firefox?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, menu

I installed a fresh ubuntu desktop 11.10 and in firefox there is no menu bar. I tried several things like

- pressing the Alt key
- F1-12
- right click on a free space in the tab bar

but still no menu bar visible in firefox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not familiar with the "global menu" - most applications have their menu appear in the top of the screen.

Simply moving you mouse into this space should be enough to display the menu:

[image]