# How come firefox has no settings?

Tags: firefox, menu, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the menu bar in firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88710/how-can-i-get-the-menu-bar-in-firefox)

I've installed the latest ubuntu. I'm using firefox and wanted to change some of the settings. But it has no menu and no where I can see to open the settings menu to change things.

This is my first attempt at installing ubuntu proper and getting this far; i.e. having a system working. I have tried several times since Ubuntu was made. The install CD has come a long way and even does the partitioning for dual boot. So I commend all the programmers for that vast improvement.
However it is things like this that are just most infuriating and off-putting when you come from widows to Ubuntu: when you can't find even a menu to work with! Has anyone any idea how to view the menu on the firefox that comes with the installation 11.10?

Answer (score 3):

You can also hover your mouse over the title of the program, here Firefox. Then the menus will show.

This is actually a feature of Ubuntu, in order to save the most space possible. This vetical space is indeed more useful for browsing for example.

Answer (score 2):

Original poster's answer.

> If you press the ALT key the menu appears on the top bar in UBUNTU's
>   desktop not on the program window itself. I'm thinking this may be the
>   case for all other programs as well so I'll try that.
>
> I think it might be a good idea to have a 'window users heads-up'
>   video or some such when you install for the first time so that novices
>   wont be so frustrated with things like these that are alien to them.

Comment: ... the global menu should become more obvious in 12.04 - the menu is briefly displayed for a few seconds when an application is first opened.