# Clearing firefox's cache

Tags: firefox, cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the menu bar in firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88710/how-can-i-get-the-menu-bar-in-firefox)

I have ubuntu installed on my mac with VirutalBox. Firefox is installed and I want to clear the cache of Firefox. I don't find any menu bar, how can I do that ?

Comment: I think the menu bar now appears on top when you hover over it.

Comment: Did that help? If yes, I request @steabert to add that comment as answer, so that you can accept it.

Comment: @steabert As Anwar says, I recommend posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to open-up cleaning dialogue.

[image]

To check what's in cache: about:cache

For further cleaning on Ubuntu install "BleachBit".

Comment: Nuts. Was pressing cntl+alt+del and nothing was happening. Must be flashbacks to windows days.

Answer (score 0):

there's something wrong from your os installation. Canonical has facilitated Firefox with Ubuntu menu bar on top of desktop like OS X and it can be marked with ubuntu originally menu bar extension in Frefox's plugins.

For alternative, you can use Ubuntu Tweak which you can get from add this ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: tualatrix/ppa
```

then update the system and the Ubuntu Tweak will be appear immidiatelly on your USC.